# Duplicating SQL rows and renaming duplicated columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table that contains something like this 

`╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ EMPID ║ UserName ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║ Josh     ║
║     2 ║ Kate     ║
║     3 ║ Josh     ║
║     4 ║ Kate     ║
║     5 ║ Kate     ║
║     6 ║ Josh     ║
║     7 ║ Morgan   ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝`

I want to duplicate all the rows that have Kate but replace Kate in the duplicates with Kathy and then duplicate all rows containing Josh but replace the duplicates with Joshy as the username. I am not sure how to go about this. Could some MySQL expert help please?

Comment: So you want to keep the existing rows like you have them, and just add 3 Kathy rows and 3 Joshy rows?

Comment: exactly. I want to be able to select the rows with Kate duplicate them but then replace Kate in the duplicates with Kathy. Same with Josh

Comment: What about *emp_id*: should it not be unique?

Comment: @trincot it should be unique. It's auto increment so no need to worry about it

Comment: Yes I have auto-increment on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert those variant records using the [`INSERT...SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (UserName)
    SELECT 'Kathy'
    FROM   mytable
    WHERE  UserName = 'Kate';
```

Then do something similar for Josh:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (UserName)
    SELECT 'Joshy'
    FROM   mytable
    WHERE  UserName = 'Josh';
```

If you prefer one SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (UserName)
    SELECT CASE UserName
               WHEN 'Kate' THEN 'Kathy'
               WHEN 'Josh' THEN 'Joshy'
           END
    FROM   mytable
    WHERE  UserName IN ('Kate', 'Josh');
```

In either case, the `SELECT` statement makes sure you get a result per instance of the duplicate (3 results for *Kate* and 3 for *John*). And for every result you provide the `UDPATE` statement the adjusted name to insert. So the correct number of records is inserted in this way.